# Decomposing a number as a sum of two products using tree recursion

Tags: python, recursion, mathematics

Below is the problem taken from page6 [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/disc/disc03.pdf).

> The TAs want to print handouts for their students. However, for some unfathomable reason, both the printers are broken; the first printer only prints multiples of `n1`, and the second printer only prints multiples of `n2`. Help the TAs figure out whether or not it is possible to print an exact number of handouts! First try to solve without a helper function. Also try to solve using a helper function and adding up to the sum.

```
def has_sum(sum, n1, n2):
"""
>>> has_sum(1, 3, 5)
False
>>> has_sum(5, 3, 5) # 1(5) + 0(3) = 5
True
>>> has_sum(11, 3, 5) # 2(3) + 1(5) = 11
True
"""
```

## Solution

I think there is no mathematical solution except bruteforce recursion.

```
def f(sum, n1, n2):
    """
    >>> f(1, 3, 5)
    False
    >>> f(5, 3, 5) # 1(5) + 0(3) = 5
    True
    >>> f(11, 3, 5) # 2(3) + 1(5) = 11
    True
    >>> f(189, 4, 9)
    True
    """
    memoiz = []
    value = []   
    def has_sum(sum, n1, n2, x=0, y=0):
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            value.append(n1)
            value.append(n2)   #execute once to reuse tup
        if (n1 + n2)  == sum:
            return True
        if (memoiz) and ((n1 + n2)  > sum): # inefficient base case, need to improve using math
            return False
        result1 = False
        result2 = False
        if (x+1, y) not in memoiz:
            memoiz.append((x+1, y)) #memoiz
            result1 = has_sum(sum, (x+1)*value[0], y*value[1], x+1, y)
        if (x, y+1) not in memoiz:
            memoiz.append((x, y+1)) #memoiz
            result2 = has_sum(sum, x*value[0], (y+1)*value[1], x, y+1)
        return result1 or result2
    return has_sum(sum, n1, n2)
```

Can we improve the base case that returns `False`?

Comment: Why are you memoizing using a list?! `in` is `O(n)` and I've already shown you how to do it with a decorator.

Comment: See [Linear Diophantine equations, two variables](http://public.csusm.edu/aitken_html/m422/Handout5.pdf)

Comment: Teacher did not teach decorator concept. I will go thru you question. I need to go thru some homework on decorators before using it.

Comment: @200_success yes, I got the same suggestion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359120/finding-sum-that-is-factor-of-n/1359126#comment2764193_1359120)

Comment: @jonrsharpe's has already mentioned in a previous answer to one of your questions that the most elegant way to memoize functions is to use a decorator. We don't mind reviewing your code, but it would be more rewarding if we can see that you are learning from our answers. (You may have noticed that your recent questions have not scored as well as your first few questions.)

Comment: It is a little bit frustrating that you don't actually appear to be reading and learning from answers to your previous questions. Perhaps aim to post less frequently, and take as much as you can from the responses to each one. There's plenty of learning material out there if you want to get ahead of the class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, but I need to work more hard, if I need to learn new concepts from the given answers. I had been thru your answer same day but, I skipped it after I saw the decorator. I will try, but decorator is not part of complete syllabus. Basically am trying to solve problems with the programming elements I can learn. With my capacity, I could grasp to add attributes within function.

Comment: @overexchange then simply *stop asking* until you've absorbed it; we aren't here just to polish up your homework.

Comment: My question is to make improve the base case that returns  `False`. I need help on this. because stack will overflow with big number

Answer (score 3):

> First try to solve without a helper function. Also try to solve using a helper function and adding up to the sum.

You haven't included an implementation without a helper function.
You implemented memoization, which was not part of the description.
In any case, memoization won't be possible without a helper function or annotations.

#### Code review

There are several problems with your implementation:

- `memoiz` shouldn't be a `list`, but a `set`
- The `value` variable is confusing: it merely stores the original values of `n1` and `n2`, you could simply save those values before calling the helper function
- `sum` is a poor name for a variable, because it shadows the built-in named "sum"
- There should be spaces around operators to improve readability, for example instead of `(x+1)*value[0]` it should be `(x + 1) * value[0]`
- Instead of multiplying `value[0]` and `value[1]`, it would be better to accumulate a sum
- If `result1` is `True`, there's no need to evaluate `result2`

With the above tips, the solution can be simplified a bit and become more efficient:

```
memoiz = set()
def has_sum(sum, n1, n2, x=0, y=0):
    if n1 + n2 == sum:
        return True
    if n1 + n2 > sum:
        return False
    if (x+1, y) not in memoiz:
        memoiz.add((x+1, y))
        result1 = has_sum(sum, n1 + orig_n1, n2, x+1, y)
        if result1:
            return True
    if (x, y+1) not in memoiz:
        memoiz.add((x, y+1))
        return has_sum(sum, n1, n2 + orig_n2, x, y+1)
    return False
orig_n1, orig_n2 = n1, n2
return has_sum(sum, 0, 0)
```

#### An alternative solution

Consider this alternative algorithm:

- If `target` is 0, then we can reach it by 0 times `n1` and `n2`
- If `target` is below 0, then we cannot reach it
- If `target` can be reached by a sum of multiples of `n1` and `n2`,
  then `target - n1` *or* `target - n2` must be reachable too

Implementation using memoization:

```
memoize = { 0: True }
def helper(target):
    if target not in memoize:
        if target < 0:
            memoize[target] = False
        else:
            memoize[target] = helper(target - n1) or helper(target - n2)
    return memoize[target]
return helper(target)
```

#### Iterative solution

At first I overlooked your requirement of a recursive solution.
For the record, this was my original suggestion using iterative logic.

---

Unless I'm missing something,
you can solve this using a much simpler algorithm:

- If a solution exists, then `sum == n1 * A + n2 * B` where `A` and `B` are integers
- Loop from `A = 0` to `sum`, by steps of `n1`
- If `sum - A` is divisible by `n2`, then a solution exists
- If the end of the loop is reached, then a solution doesn't exist

That is:

```
for A in range(0, sum + 1, n1):
    if (sum - A) % n2 == 0:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: This question is part of recursion lab

Comment: My bad, I overlooked your title. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: you said `dict` but you are using `set()`. what is the problem with `list`?

Comment: Changed the text to `set` to match the revised implementation. The problem with a `list` is that `x in somelist` is an \$O(n)\$ operation, while `x in someset` is an \$O(1)\$ operation

Comment: OK. how set is efficient from list in finding an element? What is the underlying implementation of set that it is efficient than list?

Comment: A set is implemented as a hash set

Comment: `n1 + n2 > sum` is a horrible base case for big numbers. In my above query, my question was,  can we improve this using some math, where we don't require `x` and `y` incremented to reach an efficient bases case?

Comment: See my explanation in the iterative solution, using multiplication and module. That's as close as it gets to a math formula. You should be able to reuse that logic in your recursive solution too.

Comment: this base case `n1 + n2 > sum` would not suffice for this test case `has_sum(5, 3, 5)`.  and this base case is not efficient.

Comment: In recusive code, you are not multiplying `x` with `n1` and `y` with `n2`. I did not get the logic in saying `n1+orig_n1`.

Comment: I am not multiplying, as I explained *"Instead of multiplying value[0] and value[1], it would be better to accumulate a sum"*. That's exactly what I implemented: accumulating instead of multiplication. Addition is more efficient than multiplication.