# Checking whether the some of two ranges falls within a lower and upper bound

Tags: python, recursion, interval

## [Problem 4](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/disc/disc03.pdf)

As per the given link, this exercise is part of recursion lab.

> Printer A prints a random x copies `50 ≤ x ≤ 60`, and Printer B prints a random y copies `130 ≤ y ≤ 140`. Can the two printers be used in a way that guarantees that the number of copies is between some lower and upper bound?
>
> Hint: Try using a helper function.
>
> ```
> def sum_range(lower, upper):
>     """
>     >>> sum_range(45, 60) # Printer A prints within this range
>     ;
>     ... # the TAs would be satisfied with any number it prints
>     ...
>     True
>     >>> sum_range(40, 55) # Printer A can print some number 56-60
>     ... # copies, which is not within the TA acceptable range
>     ...
>     False
>     >>> sum_range(170, 201) # Printer A + Printer B will print
>     ... # somewhere between 180 and 200 copies total
>     ...
>     True
>     """
> ```

## Solution

```
def sum_range(given_min, given_max):
    """
    >>> sum_range(45, 60) # Printer A prints within this range;
    True
    >>> sum_range(40, 55) # Printer A can print some number 56-60
    False
    >>> sum_range(170, 201) # Printer A + Printer B will print somewhere between 180 and 200 copies total
    True
    """
    def helper(print_min, print_max):
        if print_min >= given_min and print_max <= given_max:
            return True
        if print_min and (print_min < given_min or print_max > given_max): 
            return False
        return helper(50 + print_min, 60 + print_max) or helper(130 + print_min, 140 + print_max) or helper(50 + 130 + print_min, 60 + 140 + print_max)
    return helper(0, 0)
```

Tested this solution, it works.

Can this solution still be improved?

Does it make sense to memoiz this solution? Is their a chance of having similar nodes in a tree that has redundant computation?

Comment: What about using Printer A twice, etc?

Comment: @o11c Considering that this problem is part of a problem set where the [preceding question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96760/9357) was about linear combinations, I believe that it the point of the problem is to consider using Printer A and Printer B multiple times. Hence the suggestion in the problem to use recursion. I do not believe that this code solves the problem.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the class instructor's [solutions](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp14/disc/discussion03_sol.pdf) for these kinds of questions?

Comment: @200_success the solution seems correct.

Comment: @o11c you are right, I modified the solution.

Answer (score 2):

No idea about the recursion part, but a few things to mention.

This

> ```
> def helper(given_lower, given_upper, avlbl_lower, avlbl_upper):
>     if given_lower <= avlbl_lower and given_upper >= avlbl_upper:
>         return True
>     return False
> ```

can be simplified by returning the condition like

```
def helper(given_lower, given_upper, avlbl_lower, avlbl_upper):
    return given_lower <= avlbl_lower and given_upper >= avlbl_upper
```

Instead of using `result1`..`result3` I would use 2 `if` statements and return early if one of these method calls returns `true`. There is no need to call each one if the first returns `true`.

Like so

```
if helper(lower, upper, printerA[0], printerA[-1]):
    return true
if helper(lower, upper, printerB[0], printerB[-1]):
    return true

return helper(lower, upper, printerA[0] + printerB[0], printerA[-1] + printerB[-1])
```